# What can I do if I need to attend court as a witness whilst on sick leave?

Tags: sickness

I am off sick due to bulging disks and nerve compression in my spine. I have been housebound for 5 weeks, am unable to walk, and require aids like a zimmer frame, commode, and perching stool.

I am due to attend court as a witness in 4 weeks time. Whilst I'll hopefully be a lot better by then, could I get into trouble if I'm still on sick leave?

Comment: Probably better to ask on Law StackExchange. Also, contact the court in question. Answers will / should vary by country of those answering.

Comment: Are you asking if you could get in trouble because you can't attend court, or if you would get in trouble with your office for doing some other activity while you are on sick leave?

Comment: Also, talk to the counsel that is calling you as a witness; this is something that they should be able handle, rather than you having to negotiate the court system. Also, I hope you start to feel better soon.

Comment: This is for workplace questions, so if you're asking about how your employer will treat this, that is on-topic, but if you're asking how the court will treat this, that is off-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to the scope of what's on-topic for Workplace.SE. However, if you flag your own question and ask a moderator to move it to a different site (like Law.stackexchange.com) where does appear to be on topic, you have a better chance that the question won't be closed.

Comment: Mention the country where you are.

Answer (score 34):

Contact the court - they will usually delay your appearance or remove you with medical evidence.

At least that is what happened when my friend had a similar issue.

Comment: You might be able to arrange something like a written testimony or video interview.

Answer (score 17):

You asked,

> I am due to attend court as a witness in 4 weeks time hopefully I will be a lot better but if still on sick leave from work could I get into trouble?

I think there's really two related questions here that have to be answered:

- Will you be well enough to testify in court?
- Would you be well enough to go to work?

We can't answer those questions, of course, but they may not have the same answer. For instance, your provider may determine you're well enough to stand in court for a few hours or whatever is required, but you're not well enough to do your job.

If you're working with your medical team to address both questions, separately, and you're following policy at your employer regarding PTO, it is likely that your workplace will have no reason to be upset, regardless of the result.